# When to use worker and factory function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am learning angularjs from Pro angularjs by adam freeman.

This is an example he defined an directive in angularjs

```
myApp.directive("highlight", function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.day == attrs["highlight"]) {
      element.css("color", "red");
    }
  };
});
```

the first function the writer calls is factory function and it returns a worker function. I' m not able to understand why he returns another function.

When i write the code below, the code returns an error.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
myApp.directive("highlight", function (scope, element, attrs) {
  if (scope.day == attrs["highlight"]) {
    return element.css("color","red")
  }  
});
```

Comment: what is the error returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) about directives, you'll see that there are two ways you can define a directive. One is to use the directive definition object and the other is to just return a postLink function.

The example in your book shows the latter form. The reason your function doesn't work is because Angular calls your function and expects it to return a directive definition object or a postLink function. Instead the function you defined returns nothing or the result of `element.css("color", "red")` depending on your if statement.

Comment: Yup, when in doubt just go to the angular docs. They usually tend to have an example or two.