# Worker Functions vs Factory Functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm familiar with the term factory function but i'm not able to distinguish this term from 'Worker functions'...
Can someone explain the difference between both these terms?
And when we should prefer to use worker functions or in which particular situations?
Plz try to explain it with some simple example along with theory so that i can understand it better...
An Example code is here which i read:

```
myApp.directive("directiveName", function () {
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
             if (scope.value == attrs["somevalue"]) {
                 element.css("color", "red");
             }
      }
});
```

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479175/when-to-use-worker-and-factory-function-in-angularjs

Comment: @Damodar yes, but it doesn't explain any concepts. just a particular code problem.. i'm about to learn the differences b/w both these terms so that i can decide by myself when and where to use worker functions..

Comment: In what context have you seen the term "worker function"? When I google it most of the results are about web workers... but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking about.

Comment: @andyk context of worker function is angularjs, structure and layout of controllers, directives etc etc..

Comment: @MuhammadUsman could you link to an example where the term is used? I just searched the angular docs and can't find in instance of the term "worker function". Maybe there's some more common name for it

Comment: @andyk i've updated my question..

Answer (score 1):

In Angular JS we have different Module methods which accepts functions as arguments. We call them as factory functions because they create objects that Angular JS use to perform the actual work. These factory functions can return another function which is called worker function.

For example we have the following directive:
The 2nd argument to this directive is a factory function.

```
myApp.directive("myDirective",  function() { // factory function
    // implementation code goes here
});
```

The `return` statement in following factory function return another function which will be responsible to perform actual work:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective",  function() { // factory function
    return function(scope, element, attrs) { // worker function
        // implementation code goes here
    }
```

});

This function which is returned by the above factory function is generally called worker function. While in case of directives this function is commonly known as link function...